# Is there anything comparable to a ListBox like in C#?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, desktop

I have previously worked with C# programming on Windows and would now like to program a program natively with Xcode for macOS cocoa. However, I am missing the ListBox here. The goal is to display a few elements from an array one below the other, which I can then click on individually and then perform actions with them. There is the TableView in Xcode, but I don't need to make it complicated and working with it looks quite complicated.

With a ListBox this would be done with ListBox.add(). Maybe you can help me here.

Comment: A tableview is your correct tool for the job.  It's really not that complex and you could have it up and running quickly.  If you want to dabble in SwiftUI you can use the simpler `List` but with a C# background the overhead of learning SwiftUI would probably be far greater!

Comment: In macOS 12+ and with SwiftUI, you may want to give the [`Table`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/table) a try. You may also check out `LazyVStack` and `List` from SwiftUI. When using AppKit, it's `NSTableView`.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your tipps. Can you recommend a good and easy NSTableView tutorial for macOS to me?